# FullCalendar total count for each day

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have to show total count of events for each day in full calendar.
But with my conditions, the count for next month's day is also shown up in current month.

Please help me the with required condition. 
I have seen other posts too. but all in vain

This is my current code:

```
head
.js(
LIB_PATH + 'lib/jquery-ui.min.js', 'lib/fullcalendar.min.js', function()
{
    $('#calendar_container',el).fullCalendar({
        events: '/core/api/events' 
        , eventRender: function (event, element, view) { 
            if(view.) {
                var year = event.start.getFullYear(), month = event.start.getMonth() + 1, date = event.start.getDate();
            }
            var result = year + '-' + (month < 10 ? '0' + month : month) + '-' + (date < 10 ? '0' + date : date);
            $(element).addClass(result);
            var ele = $('.fc-day'+ date +''),count=$('.' + result).length;
            $(ele).find('.viewMore').remove();
            $('.fc-event').hide();
            //var eve= $('.fc-event');//.hide();
            if ( count> 0) {
            $(ele).find('.fc-day-number').after('<small class="viewMore" style="color:blue;" onmouseout="noshow(this)" onmouseover="showevents(this,'+event.start.getTime()+','+event.end.getTime()+')">'+ count+'<div class="eventshow"></div></small>');
            } 
        }
    });
});
```